# Use of PIPE and operating system commands in FILENAME statement

Tags: sas

What does below code do and what are the possible output of sas dataset new if i have below folder and sas files in the location c:/data.

new

new.sas7bat

news.sas7bat

```
filename files pipe "find c:/data -name '*.sas7bat";
data new;
  infile files lrecl=120 pad missover;
  input;
  if index(lowcase(_infile_), 'datas') then delete;
  type = 'F';
run;
```

How does _infile process in this code.

Comment: This is a question without attempts or research.  Do you have SAS ? Try your posted code -- update the question with errors or warnings you see.  The posted code was not tried, as it has missing single and double quotes, and ill-formed `find` command (presumed for Windows).  The role of automatic variable `_infile_` in association with `infile` statement is to be found in online documentation.

Comment: I dont have SAS and unix....so not able to test it

Comment: This is not a unix command, C:/ implies Windows. Also, a free version of SAS is available for learning purposes (SAS University Edition).

Comment: @Reeza - FWIW, SAS University does not support PIPE and operating system commands.

Answer (score 0):

`INFILE` statement reads the file, the `_infile_` portion is the output from the PIPE command. `INFILE` in this case simply takes the information passed from the OS, likely Windows in this case because of the `C:\` portion.

`FIND` in Windows, searches for files within the folder that have sas7bdat, so this program is likely searching the data folder for the list of SAS7BDAT files.

There is nothing in this question to indicate that UNIX is involved. FIND is a WINDOWS and/or UNIX command.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix the `find` command is a very powerful tool for searching the file system (directory tree).  Your example using `-name` predicate will return file names that match your pattern.  Because you did not limit it in any other way it will search the whole sub-tree starting from the path given.

The `_infile_` automatic variable is available when you are using `INPUT` statement in your data step. It will hold the last line that was read from the input file.  In this case the input file is the streaming of the results of your Unix find command.

Your SAS program is not really complete. Essentially you are creating a dataset with only one variable named `type` that always has the value `"F"`.  The only information is the fact that the number of observations will match the number of SAS datasets found whose name (including the directory path) does not contain the string `"datas"`.

So if you want to find the names of all SAS dataset under the path `/data` where the name (and path) do not contain the string `datas` in any mixture of case then most likely you want something like this:

```
data new;
  infile "find /data -name '*.sas7bat'" pipe truncover ;
  input fname $256. ;
  if index(lowcase(fname), 'datas') then delete;
  type='F';
run;
```